# Brainfart: How to make overflow content in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

I cant even come up with a proper subject for this one... Basically I have a box div, that when click expands to a rectangle and shows content in the new expanded area.

The problem I'm having is that when I animate out the div's width, the browser wants to render the content as the box is stretching, rather than just have it placed where I need it.

Initial State

```
 ____  
|    |  
|____|
```

Clicked

```
 _________________  
|      Content    |  
|_________________|
```

How it currently renders

```
 __________  
|      Con |  
|______tent|
```

How I want it to render:

```
 __________  
|      Cont|ent (overflow:hidden)  
|__________|
```

Someone help me out here... total brainfart.

Comment: is the `overflow` set to hidden to start with?

Comment: Don't put tags in your title, this *is precisely* what the tag field is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with jQuery

```
$(div).click( 
   function(){ 
       $(this).animate({clip: 'rect(50px, 50px, 50px, 50px)'}); 
   },
```

Example: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/clipFx/

Answer (score 5):

This is a CSS problem ..

if you want the text in the div to not wrap at the end you will need to use the CSS

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

(*along with the `overflow:hidden`*)

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/sy6vX/